# Hide a div element when I click everywhere inside a map and not on the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Sorry for this is very basic but I'm still learning to create a basic map program. I want to hide a Div element when I'm not clicking on the marker. I managed to **show** a div using a click event something like this code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
});

marker.addListener('click', function(event) {

    // show a div  

});
```

But how to hide a div when I'm clicking outside of the marker?
[image]

Comment: You want to hide div when clicking outside the marker(anywhere on map)?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide a div anywhere on map. And show it when I click the marker.

Comment: maybe you mean infowindow? or your custom div?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just add click event for your map:**

```
var my_div = document.getElementsByClassName("custom_div")[0];
var jq_my_div = $('.custom_div'); // Jquery

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        my_div.style.display = 'none';
        jq_my_div.hide(); // Jquery
});
```

*When you click on marker - it doesnt't react on map click event.*

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/2814/

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!